# Como fazer disparar o evento de drop ao apertar enter no ExtJs

Tags: extjs, drag-n-drop

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu disparar um evento de drop ao apertar enter em uma TreePanel.
Eu não estou conseguindo disparar o evento manualmente, o que eu consegui até agora:

```
mediaCenter.getEl().addKeyMap({
    eventName: "keyup",
    binding: [{
        key: Ext.EventObject.ENTER,
        fn: function() {
            var node = mediaCenter.view.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
            node = node[0];
            var model = mediaCenter.view.getSelectionModel();
            var args = new Object({
                                    node: node,
                                    dropPosition: 1
                                });
            grid.fireEvent('beforeDrop', args);
            console.log(node);
        }
    }]
}));
```

Eu quero que quando o usuário apertar enter, o nó que está selecionado vá para a grid que eu criei.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia.

Se você quer que ao apertar o enter aconteça o evento eu acho que não seria implementado no *drag and drop*.

Já tentou fazer esta lógica no evento [*itemkeydown*](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-event-itemkeydown) do *TreePanel* assim você identifica a tecla *enter* e remove o *node* da *Tree* e adiciona os valores na *Grid*
Espero ter ajudado